# Where is my keyboard, mouse and other HCI devices mounted in linux?

Tags: usb

i have heard that everything in linux is treated as files.. i was just curious as to where would i find to explore the usb mounted on my machine (HCI dev)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get a list of USB devices connected to your machine via the command:

```
lsusb
```

You can monitor input events from USB and other devices via:

```
evtest
```

which will also tell you the device path (e.g. mouse and keyboard, as well as power button, etc.) in `/dev/input/event*`.  You might need to install the `evtest` package for that.

This is a script (taken from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144029/command-to-determine-ports-of-a-device-like-dev-ttyusb0) on Unix SE) which searches `/sys` looking for USB devices (i.e. the ones with a ID_SERIAL attribute):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for sysdevpath in $(find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev); do
    (
        syspath="${sysdevpath%/dev}"
        devname="$(udevadm info -q name -p $syspath)"
        [[ "$devname" == "bus/"* ]] && exit
        eval "$(udevadm info -q property --export -p $syspath)"
        [[ -z "$ID_SERIAL" ]] && exit
        echo "/dev/$devname - $ID_SERIAL"
    )
done
```

Comment: i ran the evtest commmand... i chose for the touchpad event... i saw that the output also gives me value of pressure i apply on touchpad... can u pls share the code ,running which i get a pop up (sort of toast ) if i press the touch pad hard

Comment: moreover when i cd /dev/input/ i see something called as "mice" "mouse1" "mouse0" and "mouse2" other than the directory by-id and by-path and the 13 events that evtest command would anyways display... how can make use of these "mice" "mouse1" "mouse0" and "mouse2"?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you connect usb devices. When you type:

```
lsusb
```

you have list connected usb devices. You can read bus and device number. Then when you type:

```
lsusb -t
```

( bus and device number are known from lsusb ) you can read port number of device you are checking.
e.g my mouse is on bus 001, device 004 and this belongs to port 14.

Now when you go to:

```
/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb
```

you can see there is e.g symlink 1-14 which is responsible for my mouse (bus 1, port 14). You can use **realpath 1-14** command to see where this symlink leads
(You can disable this port by typing: *echo '1-14' | sudo tee unbind* )

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It helped me disable my mouse from waking my computer.